# How can I insert IF in where cluase? (TSQL)

Tags: t-sql

I have this query in TSQL

```
DECLARE @DATA_INIZIO AS DATE
DECLARE @DATA_FINE AS DATE    
SELECT 'TEMPERATURA RILEVATA', VS.EffectiveTimeMin as ORA, CAST(VS.Value AS INT), row_number() over (order by VS.EffectiveTimeMin) AS CONTEGGIO
        FROM AA_V_PHR_CCD_VitalSigns V INNER JOIN AA_V_PHR_CCD_VitalSignsXResults VS ON V.ID = VS.IDVitalSigns
        WHERE V.IDResultTypeValueSet = 23 AND V.IDClinicalDocument = 46
        ORDER BY VS.EffectiveTimeMin asc
```

But, I want to add this condiTIon at the where clause:

```
IF(@Data_Inizio is not null and @Data_Fine is not null)
   v.effectivetime between @data_inizio and @data_fine
```

how can I do this?

Comment: try to add this line in your WHERE clause: AND ( (@DATA_INIZIO is null OR @DATA_FINE is null) OR (@DATA_INIZIO <= v.effectivetime AND v.effectivetime <= @DATA_FINE) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add those lines in your WHERE clause:

```
SELECT
    'TEMPERATURA RILEVATA',
    VS.EffectiveTimeMin as ORA,
    CAST(VS.Value AS INT),
    row_number() over (order by VS.EffectiveTimeMin) AS CONTEGGIO
FROM
    AA_V_PHR_CCD_VitalSigns V
    INNER JOIN AA_V_PHR_CCD_VitalSignsXResults VS
        ON V.ID = VS.IDVitalSigns
WHERE
    V.IDResultTypeValueSet = 23
    AND V.IDClinicalDocument = 46
    AND ( (@DATA_INIZIO is null OR @DATA_FINE is null)
        OR                                                -- when both are not null
        (@DATA_INIZIO <= v.effectivetime AND v.effectivetime <= @DATA_FINE)
        )
ORDER BY VS.EffectiveTimeMin ASC
```

you can 'translate' your IF statement to sth like:
 when DATA_INIZIO or DATA_FINE is not set (null) then return record
 when they are both set - check if v.effectivetime fits their range

Answer (score 2):

```
(
    (@Data_Inizio is not null and @Data_Fine is not null) 
    AND 
    v.effectivetime between @data_inizio and @data_fine
)
```

Should be fine if I understood you properly.

Hmm maybe you don't have properly values, or your dates are incorrect, look at my sample below:

```
DECLARE @DATA_INIZIO AS DATE = '2017/01/01'
DECLARE @DATA_FINE AS DATE = '2017/02/01'

Declare @Tmp Table 
(
    IdResult Int, IdClinical Int, EffectiveTime DateTime
)

Insert Into @Tmp (IdResult, IdClinical, EffectiveTime)
Values 
    (23, 46, '2017/01/23'), (22, 46, '2017/01/23'),
    (23, 46, '2017/01/2'), (23, 47, '2017/01/23'),
    (23, 46, '2017/01/5'), (23, 46, '2017/02/23')

SELECT *
FROM 
    @Tmp V
WHERE 
    V.IdResult = 23 AND V.IdClinical = 46
    AND
    (
        (@Data_Inizio is null OR @Data_Fine is null) 
        OR 
        v.effectivetime between @data_inizio and @data_fine
    )
```

Comment: Your query is correct, but not return never value and this is not correct.
If I delete your code a have 5 records. If I insert your code, and set DataInizio e DataFine = NULL I don't have never result

Comment: Oh.. so you want to have data if the dates are nulls? So yours condition was wrong. Give me a minute.

Comment: I edited the condition, but I see that P. ejh did that faster ;)